# Spring boot integration - ref not recognizing bean for adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to build a spring boot project with spring integration to handle incoming as2 messages using a custom inbound-channel-adapter. for some reason the ref argument of the adapter is not finding a bean definition for my class.

I have the followed spring reference files and online resources and have the following understanding:

1. Adding the `@ImportResource("/integration/integration.xml")` annotation pointing to my spring integration xml file adds it to the application context

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("/integration/integration.xml")
public class MyApplication implements ServletContextListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
```

2. adding the `@Component` annotation above my class should make it autodetectable as a bean by my spring boot application

```
@Component
public class MyHandlerModule extends AbstractProcessorModule implements IProcessorStorageModule {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandlerModule.class);


    @Override
    public boolean canHandle(@Nonnull String s, @Nonnull IMessage iMessage, @Nullable Map<String, Object> map) {
        LOGGER.info(" Handle Info:" + s);
        LOGGER.info(map.toString());
        return s.equals(DO_STORE);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void handle(@Nonnull String s, @Nonnull IMessage iMessage, @Nullable Map<String, Object> map) {
        LOGGER.info("----- AS2 MESSAGE RECEIVED !!! ------");
}
}
```

3. and yet I am getting an error when running the application in my `integration.xml` file with the following message:

```
A component required a bean named 'com.example.MyHandlerModule' that could not be found.
```

For reference, here is my `integration.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



    <int:channel id="as2MessageChannel"/>



    <int:inbound-channel-adapter id="as2" ref="com.example.MyHandlerModule" method="handle" channel="as2MessageChannel"/>

</beans>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is correct : without any custom name the framework makes it like `myHandlerModule` - the camel case based on a simple class name . The package is not involved in bean naming . Not sure what made you to point fully qualified class name in that ref…

Comment: thanks! when i referenced  ```ref="myHandlerModuler"``` with camel case I was able to get it to work!